# How to prevent a new instance of SQL Server Management Studio from opening when opening with a click a .sql file when I already have another one open?

Tags: file, ssms

I have open an instance of sql server management studio and try to open a .sql file previously saved on my computer.

However, the file opens in a new instance of sql server when I click it, instead of being opened in the one I already have open.

I've tried dragging the file and drop it into the Query Editor, but it also does not allow it to be opened as well.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Management Studio, look in the upper left hand corner for the "Open File" icon and click on it. You can also try Ctrl + O. Navigate to your file and select it.

[image]

Comment: Really this is what I do not want. I want to open the files in the current instance with the click. I think it will be more specific in my question.